# CKAN file upload 413 Request Entity Too Large error in Ngnix

Tags: file-upload, ckan

I need to be able to upload files ranging in size in 500MBs in CKan. I have installed CKAN using packager in Ubuntu 16x version. It works nice with me being able to set up organizations and creating new datasets. However, I am not able to upload files more than 100mb in size. I get error

> *413 Request Entity Too Large error' nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)*

Based on various forums and suggestions, I have changed 
***client_max_body_size*** to 1g in file ***/etc/nginx/nginx.conf***. I have tried various ways such as setting this parameter to ***1000M/1g/1G*** values one at a time and nothing seems to work. My all uploads beyond ***100MB*** keep failing.

I also learnt that changing ***production.ini or development.ini(ckan.max_resource_size)*** file would help and I tried that too but it doesn't work. Please suggest what could be done. nginx is a proxy server and apache is web server that comes with default cKan packager.

Comment: Could you share the snippet of nginx.conf or other conf file used in ngnix?

Answer (score 0):

In the end of **/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**, you have this include directive :

> include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

that will include **/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ckan**. This file contains the directive :

> client_max_body_size 100M;

Change it, don't forget to change the *ckan.max_resource_size* **/etc/ckan/default/production.ini**, restart nginx and apache and it will work normally.

Comment: Ckan production.ini file also has upload limit as does data pusher configs. All of which could be causing an issue. => [Max resource size](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/maintaining/configuration.html#ckan-max-resource-size) | [data pusher limit](https://docs.ckan.org/projects/datapusher/en/latest/using.html#configuring-the-maximum-upload-size)